# Create a dictionary / map type column from an array column in pyspark such that the key should be same for all array elements

Tags: python, arrays, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark data frame as below:
The schema of the dataframe is also given below:

```
|-- array_list: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
|-- len_of_array: integer (nullable = false)
```

dataframe

```
+---------------+--------------+
|array_list     |len_of_array  |
+---------------------+--------+
|[t1, t2, t3]   |3             |
|[t1, t2]       |2             |
|[t2]           |1             |
+---------------------+--------+
```

How can we create a new column-"mappings" wherein a constant key-"mapname" is mapped to each of the elements in array in column-"array_list"
The expected output is

```
+---------------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------+
|array_list     |len_of_array  |mappings                                            |
+---------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------+                 
|[t1, t2, t3]   |3             |[[mapname -> t1], [mapname -> t2], [mapname -> t3]] |
|[t1, t2]       |2             |[[mapname -> t1], [mapname -> t2]]                  |
|[t2]           |1             |[[mapname -> t2]]                                   | 
+---------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

mapname (i.e. the key) is a string i.e."mapname" and should be same for all array elements

I have created an additional column -"increasing_id" which has values -1,2,3 and then tried to define a UDF and use it in for loop to update each row of the mappings column, but its giving an error.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql import types as T  
@udf(T.MapType(T.StringType(), T.StringType())) 
def create_dict(name_value):
    return {"name": name_value}
```

And then finally use a for loop to populate the column values:

```
for j in range(3):
    result = df2.where(df2.increasing_id == j).select("len_of_array")
    result = result.collect()[0][0]
    df = df.where(df.increasing_id == j)\ 
           .withColumn('mappings',
                       array([create_dict(df.array_list.getItem(i)) for i in range(0,result)])) 

Error:
An error was encountered:
list index out of range
Traceback (most recent call last):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The expected schema would look like this..

```
|-- mappings: array (nullable = false)
|    |-- element: map (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- key: string
|    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

Comment: duplicate key names are not allowed in a map type column. If there are duplicate keys, which value would you fetch for a given key?

Comment: i want to keep the "key" to be same for all the elements and while extracting/fetching-- all the key values will be used as there is no requirement to extract any particular key value.

Comment: that's simply not possible in Spark. map type columns are not designed for this purpose.

Comment: I have created an additional column -"increasing_id" which has index -1,2,3 and then  tried to define a UDF and use it in for loop to update each row of the mappings column, but the final dataframe is empty. Attaching the code below:

`from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql import types as T

@udf(T.MapType(T.StringType(), T.StringType()))
def create_dict(name_value):
    return {"name": name_value}`

Comment: And then finally use a for loop to populate the column values:
`for j in range(3):
    result = df2.where(df2.increasing_id == j).select("len_of_array")
    result = result.collect()[0][0]
    df = df.where(df.increasing_id == j)\
             .withColumn('mappings', array([create_dict(df.array_list.getItem(i)) for i in range(0,result)]))`

Comment: [Edit] your question to add details. Comments are not intended for adding information to your question.

Comment: can you show your output or excepted print schema ?

Comment: I have updated the schema in the question

Comment: @R__: What is your question? As mck pointed out, your desired result is not possible due to restrictions in MapType. What do you want to achieve with the function you wrote?

Comment: I want to populate the "mappings" column in the dataframe. from the array_list. With the udf mentioned in the question i was able to populate the mappings column wherein the array list was all of the same size (i.e. all the records has same number of elements in the array.-[test1, test2, test3]. I was able to achieve this using
`df.withColumn('mappings', array([create_dict(df.array_list.getItem(i)) for i in range(0,3)]))` But i want to replicate this for array_list which do not have same number of elements in it.

Comment: Finally I want to write this DF into a json file where it looks like this:-
{"mappings":[{"mapname":"test1"},{"mapname":"test2"},{"mapname":"test3"}]}----This is for record 1
depending upon the number of elements in the array list.